# Adding jQuery array value to another array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, wordpress

I am doing some thing which is really looks messy to me :( I just want to add my jquery code like shown below:

```
var $container = [
        $('#gallery-listed0'), 
        $('#gallery-listed1')
    ], 
    $optionSets = [
        $('#filterlist_v50 .filter_testing'), 
        $('#filterlist_v51 .filter_testing')
    ];
```

Now, this above data is working fine but I want to get same data by using any for loop ... is it possible ? Can I get same as :

```
var $container = [
         $('#gallery-listed0'), 
         $('#gallery-listed1')
    ], 
    $optionSets = [
         $('#filterlist_v50 .filter_testing'), 
         $('#filterlist_v51 .filter_testing')
    ];
```

Using for loop in jQuery ?

Note: This data will be addable as well, if an other data needed say 3rd item, that will also be there in same way like shown below:

```
var $container = [
        $('#gallery-listed0'), 
        $('#gallery-listed1'), 
        $('#gallery-listed2')
    ], 
    $optionSets = [
        $('#filterlist_v0 .filter_testing'), 
        $('#filterlist_v1 .filter_testing'), 
        $('#filterlist_v2 .filter_testing')
    ];
```

I tried a lot but could not get this one to work.

As this data is inside my html but I want to run only one loop in jquery to make my code dynamic.

I tried this method

```
var count = 2;
var container = [];
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    container.push('$("#gallery-listed'+i+'")');
    //alert(container);     
}
var dataNow = container.toString();
```

It alerts my data as wanted, but I want to have this data in same fashion as I shown above in my very first code line ... any one please ???

Comment: Why not just add classes to those elements, and do `$('.className')` to get them all

Comment: you had done mistake in push the jquery object.

Comment: Try  `container.push($("#gallery-listed"+i));`

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    container.push($('#gallery-listed'+i));
}

Comment: No, I don't want to just push in jquery ... I want all that data by using a loop or any trick plzz ... but making it dynamic ... means the many in html page would all come in my js in simple words ..

Comment: Can you paste all of your html in here? It sounds like you want to loop through certain elements to put them into the respective arrays.

Comment: Will be pasting all my html in the question